# Can a title of a node not be associated with a url?

Tags: nodes, uri

I want to create a node with multiple urls.  I don't want the title of the main node to be a url.  Right now the main node is being pulled up in a list view through taxonomy.  When I create multiple nodes for the main node, it shows up multiple times in the taxonomy list as the same item.

I want the main node to show up once in the list with all the "sub-nodes" clickable in the main node's summary view.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> When I create multiple nodes for the main node

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? How do you create multiple nodes of the "main" node, how are they related to each other?

CCK has a node reference field, you should use that to make the relationships explicit and go from there.

Comment: I guess what I have going on here is a one to many relationship.  One node has 4 links.  Each of those links link to one node.  All of them are tagged with the same taxonomy term.  When I go to the taxonomy page, all 4 "sub-nodes" show up because they've been tagged.  However, I just want the "main" node to appear once, sort of like a group container of all 4 nodes, rather than 4 individual nodes in the taxonomy list.  Hope this makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating 2 different content types, one "main" for your main node and another for your "link" node.
Then you make CCK node reference between them and in the views you just display "main" nodes.